# Count the lines from output using pipeline

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to count how many files have words with the pattern `[Gg]reen`.

```
    #!/bin/bash
      for File in `ls ./`
      do
      cat ./$File | egrep '[Gg]reen' | sed -n '$='
      done
```

When I do this I get this output:

```
1
1
3
1
1
```

So I want to count the lines to get in total 5. I tried using `wc -l` after the sed but it didn't work; it counted the lines in all the files. I tried to use `>file.txt` but it didn't write anything on it. And when I use `>>` instead it writes but when I execute the shell it appends the lines again.

Comment: remember you are counting lines per file...so you need an counter like `let count+=$(cat ./$File | egrep '[Gg]reen' | wc -l)` should sum the lines..., sed edits the files i dont think you want to edit the file

Comment: I'm confused; if you just want the number of files with matches, what's the point of using `sed` to get the number of matches *per file*?

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep

Comment: `grep -c` will count the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since according to your question, you want to know *how many files* contain a pattern, you are interested in the number of files, not the number of pattern occurances.

For instance,

```
grep -l '[Gg]reen' *  | wc -l
```

would produce the number of files which contain somewhere *green* or *Green* as a substring.